# error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: how to fix?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, jar

I have a problem, when i running this code, i found this problem. how to fix it ?

**this code**

```
      

      public class kpi {
      static String host = "";
      
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        host = args[0].toLowerCase();
        try {
          SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
          Date now = new Date();
          String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);
          JSch jsch = new JSch();
          Session session = jsch.getSession("hs", args[1], 22);
          session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
          session.setPassword("kti365LM");
          session.connect();
          System.out.println("session connected");
          Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
          OutputStream ops = channel.getOutputStream();
          PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(ops, true);
          channel.connect();
          System.out.println("channel connected");
          String prompt = "[local]" + args[0] + "#";
          System.out.println(exec(channel, ps, "epg node status", prompt));
          String nodeinfo = "";
          nodeinfo = exec(channel, ps, "pdc_kpi.pl", prompt);
          String[] linenode = nodeinfo.split("\\r?\\n");
          String key = "";
          JSONObject peerjson = new JSONObject();
          peerjson.put("time", strDate.replace(" ", "T"));
          peerjson.put("node", args[0]);
          for (int i = 6; i  0 && c  0) {`
                    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)");
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(fields[j]);
                    if (m.find()) {
                      System.out.println(key + ":" + m.group());
                      peerjson.put(key, Float.parseFloat(m.group().trim()));
                      c++;
                    } 
                  } 
                  key = key + fields[j];
                  c++;
                } 
                if (j > 4 && c == 0)
                  break; 
              } 
              key = "";
            } 
          } 
          insert(strDate, "nodekpimme", peerjson.toString());
          channel.disconnect();
          session.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } 
      }
```

and this error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for  length 0  at trcrt.kpi.main(kpi.java:24)`

Comment: What is line 24 exactly? Could you add the entire Java class including imports?

Comment: line 24 is "host = args[0].toLowerCase();"

Comment: I've found the answer to this case.Turns out the problem was an incorrect JDK version. when I changed JDK version and it worked. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index 0 would be first element but you have no elements in your args.You are probably running your app without arguments. You need to [pass them to args](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) variable if you want them to be available.

Comment: I've found the answer to this case.Turns out the problem was an incorrect JDK version. when I changed JDK version and it worked. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a lot messy. I think **i = 6**, why is 6 here. You should carefully trace get the value of **fields[j]**. You can finally get the answer

Comment: for (int i = 6; i < linenode.length - 2; i++) {
        if (!linenode[i].contains("=")) {
          String[] fields = linenode[i].split(" ");
          int c = 0;
          for (int j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
            if (fields[j].length() > 0 && c < 3) {
              if (c > 0) {
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(fields[j]);
                if (m.find()) {
                  System.out.println(key + ":" + m.group());
                  peerjson.put(key, Float.parseFloat(m.group().trim()));

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running without passing any argument to you main(). Try to catch this error by surrounding "host = args[0].toLowerCase();" in a try-catch block or even better control the existence of args and args.length>1 and return with an error message if the args is empty.